# Orientation lock is not working in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, orientation

I have to lock the single viewcontroller to landscape and other viewcontroller rotate all side. I have tried the below code. But the view orientation is not changed as landscape. Please give your suggestions.

AppDelegate.cs

```
public bool RestrictRotation
{
   get;
   set;
}

[Export("application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:")]
public UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, IntPtr
    forWindow)
{
    if (this.RestrictRotation)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
}
```

Viewcontroller.cs

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    this.RestrictRotation(true);
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
{
    return false;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
}

void RestrictRotation(bool restriction)
{
    AppDelegate app = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    app.RestrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the following code in the ViewController

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
   base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

   AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
   appDelegate.allowRotation = true;

   UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
   base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

   AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
   appDelegate.allowRotation = false;

   UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Unknown), new NSString("orientation"));
}
```

In addition , don't forget to check the **requires full screen** in **info.plist** , otherwise it won't work on some full screen device (like iPad Pro).

[image]

Comment: there is no ''allowRotation"' property in appDelegare.

Comment: use  `RestrictRotation` .

Comment: No still the viewcontroller is not rotating.

Comment: It works fine on my side , you could share your sample and I will test it on my side .

Comment: Please find the sample attachment from the link. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12JUcJ8ZJiiT7ep6n82-XTUq7NHgHn2JF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203581/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-dotnetuser).